# Mostrar valor según dato en tabla MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select, while

Tengo una tabla que se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera pinto la tabla completa que se muestra en la imagen la debería cargarme los datos de la columna cumple con lo que esta en Base de datos pero solo de muestra un valor

Los datos de la columna Cumple los cargo de base de datos así:

```html
<div class="container">

                <table width="auto" class="table table-responsive table-hover">

                    <thead>
                        <tr class="headings">
                            <th class="column-title">Código </th>
                            <th class="column-title">Descripción </th>                    
                            <th class="column-title">Obligatorio </th>
                            <th class="column-title">Cumple </th>                                    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>    
                        <?php
                        $sql_N0 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n0 WHERE id_protocolo = 1");

                        foreach ($sql_N0 as $value_N0) {
                            $id_N0 = $value_N0['id'];
                            $codigo_N0 = $value_N0['codigo'];
                            $descripcion_N0 = $value_N0['descripcion'];
                            ?>

                            <tr>                  
                                <td><strong><?php echo $codigo_N0; ?> </strong></td>                                       
                                <td><strong><?php echo $descripcion_N0; ?> </strong></td>                                                                         
                            </tr>  

                            <?php
                            $sql_N1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n1 WHERE id_tema_n0 =" . $id_N0);

                            foreach ($sql_N1 as $value_N1) {
                                $id_N1 = $value_N1['id'];
                                $codigo_N1 = $value_N1['codigo'];
                                $descripcion_N1 = $value_N1['descripcion'];
                                ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong><?php echo $codigo_N1; ?> </strong></td>                                       
                                    <td><strong><?php echo $descripcion_N1; ?> </strong></td>                                                                                   
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                $sql_N2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n2 WHERE id_tema_n1 = " . $id_N1);

                                foreach ($sql_N2 as $value_N2) {
                                    $id_N2 = $value_N2['id'];
                                    $codigo_N2 = $value_N2['codigo'];
                                    $descripcion_N2 = $value_N2['descripcion'];
                                    ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><strong><?php echo $codigo_N2; ?> </strong></td>                                       
                                        <td><strong><?php echo $descripcion_N2; ?> </strong></td> 
                                    </tr>   

                                    <?php
                                    $sql_N3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n3 WHERE id_tema_n2 = " . $id_N2);

                                    foreach ($sql_N3 as $value_N3) {
                                        $id_N3 = $value_N3['id'];
                                        $codigo_N3 = $value_N3['codigo'];
                                        $descripcion_N3 = $value_N3['descripcion'];
                                        $obligatorio = $value_N3['obligatorio'];

                                        if ($obligatorio == 1) {
                                            $obliga = 'Si';
                                        } elseif ($obligatorio == 0) {
                                            $obliga = 'No';
                                        }

                                        $respuestas = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE codigo_N3 like '$codigo_N3'");

                                        foreach ($respuestas as $value_est) {
                                            $id_estado_resp = $value_est['id_estado_respuesta'];

                                            $estados = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM estados_respuestas WHERE id = $id_estado_resp");

                                            foreach ($estados as $est) {
                                                $nombre_est_resp = $est['nombre'];
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $codigo_N3; ?></td>                                       
                                            <td><?php echo $descripcion_N3; ?></td> 
                                            <td style="text-align:center"><strong><?php echo $obliga ?></strong></td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center"><strong><?php echo $nombre_est_resp ?></strong></td>

                                        </tr>   

                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                    </tbody>


        <div class="container">

          <table width="auto" class="table table-responsive table-hover">

            <thead>
              <tr class="headings">
                <th class="column-title">Código </th>
                <th class="column-title">Descripción </th>
                <th class="column-title">Obligatorio </th>
                <th class="column-title">Cumple </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

              <?php
                            while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_array($respuestas)) {

                                $id_resp = $resp['id'];
                                $id_estado_resp = $resp['id_estado_respuesta'];
                                $codigo_N0_resp = $resp['codigo_N0'];
                                $codigo_N1_resp = $resp['codigo_N1'];
                                $codigo_N2_resp = $resp['codigo_N2'];
                                $codigo_N3_resp = $resp['codigo_N3'];
                            }

                            $sql_resp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM estados_respuestas WHERE id = $id_estado_resp");

                            if ($est_resp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_resp)) {
                                $id_er = $est_resp['id'];
                                $nombre_er = $est_resp['nombre'];
                            }

                            $sql_N0 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n0 WHERE id_protocolo = 1");

                            while ($value_N0 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_N0)) {
                                $id_N0 = $value_N0['id'];
                                ?>

                <tr>
                  <td><strong><?php echo $value_N0['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
                  <td><strong><?php echo $value_N0['descripcion']; ?> </strong></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                                $sql_N1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n1 WHERE id_tema_n0 =" . $id_N0);

                                while ($value_N1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_N1)) {
                                    $id_N1 = $value_N1['id'];
                                    ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td><strong><?php echo $value_N1['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
                    <td><strong><?php echo $value_N1['descripcion']; ?> </strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>

                  <?php
                                    $sql_N2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n2 WHERE id_tema_n1 = " . $id_N1);

                                    while ($value_N2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_N2)) {
                                        $id_N2 = $value_N2['id'];
                                        ?>

                    <tr>
                      <td><strong><?php echo $value_N2['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
                      <td><strong><?php echo $value_N2['descripcion']; ?> </strong></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                                        $sql_N3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM temas_n3 WHERE id_tema_n2 = " . $id_N2);

                                        while ($value_N3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_N3)) {
                                            $id_N3 = $value_N3['id'];
                                            $co_N3 = $value_N3['codigo'];
                                            $obligatorio = $value_N3['obligatorio'];

                                            if ($co_N3 = $codigo_N3_resp && $obligatorio == 1) {
                                                $obliga = 'Si';
                                            } elseif ($co_N3 = $codigo_N3_resp && $obligatorio == 0) {
                                                $obliga = 'No';
                                            }
                                            ?>

                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <?php echo $value_N3['codigo']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <?php echo $value_N3['descripcion']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><strong><?php echo $obliga ?></strong></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                          <?php echo $nombre_er ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <?php
                                        }//End while TEMA_N0
                                        ?>
                        <?php
                                    }//End while TEMA_N1
                                    ?>
                          <?php
                                }//End while TEMA_N2
                                ?>
                            <?php
                            }//End while TEMA_N3
                            ?>

            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <!--<form method="post" target="_blank" action="Genera_PDF.php">-->
            <form method="post" target="_blank" action="Genera_PDF.php">
              <input type="hidden" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $id_empresa ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="reporte_name" value="<?php echo $h1; ?>">
              <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Generar PDF">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

De acuerdo a lo que contiene la tabla estados_respuestas los datos que hay son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo a todo le pone el mismo nombre "No Cumple", cuando realmente no es así, si vemos la tabla respuestas, que se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aclarame una duda Julian, y si puedes, muestra las tablas completas. Tienes la tabla `estados_respuestas` y la tabla `respuestas`. Y como es que obtienes `$respuestas` tambien ?

Comment: Por que la consulta la realizo antes: $respuestas = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE id_empresa = $id_empresa ORDER BY id ASC");

Comment: Agrega el código faltante y revisa tus anidados, lo mejor es imprimir por pantalla el dato. Asi verás que esta llegando y por que solo te da 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tu error:**

Hacer esto hará que la variable `$id_estado_resp` siempre tome el último valor.

```
while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($respuestas)) {
   
    $id_estado_resp = $resp['id_estado_respuesta'];       
}
```

Por lo que si el último registro tuvo como respuesta "No Cumple", obtendrás ese y en tu siguiente línea:

```
$sql_resp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM estados_respuestas WHERE id = $id_estado_resp");
```

Obtendrás sólo aquellos que sean "No Cumple".

**Solución:**

Tu problema es que traes la data por separado, cuando claramente ambas tablas están relacionadas. Lo que debes hacer es un `INNER JOIN` para obtener el `estado_respuesta` asociado a esa `respuesta`.

```
SELECT 
    rep.*,
    est.nombre AS nombre_estado_respuesta
FROM respuestas AS rep
INNER JOIN estados_respuestas AS est ON
    est.id = rep.id_estado_respuesta
WHERE id_empresa = ...
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Así obtienes todo lo que necesitas en una sola consulta.

```
$query = "SELECT rep.*, est.nombre AS nombre_estado_respuesta";
$query.= "FROM respuestas AS rep";
$query.= "INNER JOIN estados_respuestas AS est ON";
$query.= "est.id = rep.id_estado_respuesta";
$query.= "WHERE id_empresa = {$id_empresa}";
$query.= "ORDER BY id ASC";
    
$respuestas = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Y no es necesario hacer una consulta por separado. Como ves, obtendras el `nombre_estado_respuesta` para cada fila de tu tabla `respuestas`.

Comment: Lo aplique así pero no me funciono, me sigue cargando el ultimo registro

Comment: Tu segundo while debes borrarlo, sólo debe quedar uno solo. Y renderizar tu tabla con esos datos. Deberías mostrar cómo construyes tu tabla de manera completa, porque sólo pusiste una parte.

Comment: Listo ya arriba agregue todo el código de como pinto la tabla completa

Comment: Por como yo lo veo, tu tabla principal debería sacarse de la tabla respuestas, pero en tu código el while() para tu tabla respuestas se cierra directamente, deberías analizar mejor y qué tabla es mandatoria, ya que son varios bucles anidados pero en ningun momento iteras por respuestas, sólo una vez y ya, por eso obtienes un sólo resultado igual.